# How can I move an article element with arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an `article` element that has a list inside of it it. What I am trying to achieve is to move the article either to the left or to the right based on what keyboard arrow is pressed. However, it doesn't do anything when I press the arrows, any suggestions on how to fix this?

```js
function addMessage(elementId, message) {
  var browserList = document.getElementById(elementId),
    newItem = document.createElement('li');

  newItem.textContent = message;
  browserList.appendChild(newItem);

}

addMessage('browser', 'page loaded');

document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addMessage('user', 'totally clicked it');
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function keyboardedIt(event) {

  var oldLeft = getComputedStyle(document.body).left,
    newLeft;

  oldLeft = parseInt(oldLeft);

  if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    newLeft = oldLeft - 10;
  } else if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    newLeft = oldLeft + 10;
  }

  document.body.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
});
```

```css
article {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <ul id="browser">
  </ul>
  <ul id="user">
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: can you try "keypress" event?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of errors in your code I had to debug, but it worked finally. First of all your article element has an auto value for "left". Go and define value like this;

```
article {
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

Now we have an actual value for left, which is 0.
I gave an article class to your article as well, see the js code below.

```
const article = document.querySelector(".article"); // I gave a article class to article

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function keyboardedIt(event) { //use keydown event
  const oldLeft = getComputedStyle(article).left; // get article's left 
  let newLeft;


  if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    newLeft = `${parseInt(oldLeft) - 10}px`; // template literals 
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
    newLeft = `${parseInt(oldLeft) + 10}px`;
  }
 article.style.left = newLeft; });
```

Also html ;

```
 <article class="article">
      <ul id="browser">
      </ul>
      <ul id="user">
      </ul>
    </article>
```